# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for org.jboss.quickstarts.fuse:cxf-soap:6.2.1.redhat-084

Tags: java, maven, jboss, cxf, camel-cxf

I am trying to run one of the Red Hat example project: cxf-soap, but encountered below error in POM.xml file.

*> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for > org.jboss.quickstarts.fuse:cxf-soap:6.2.1.redhat-084: Failure to find > org.jboss.quickstarts.fuse:cxf:pom:6.2.1.redhat-084 in http:// > maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/ was cached in the local repository, > resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of > redhat-ga-repository has elapsed or updates are forced and > 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM*

POM.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.jboss.quickstarts.fuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf</artifactId>
   <version>6.2.1.redhat-084</version>
  </parent> 

    <groupId>org.jboss.quickstarts.fuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-soap</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1.redhat-084</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>JBoss Fuse Quickstart: soap</name>
    <description>SOAP example using JAXWS</description>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
      <cxf-version>3.0.2</cxf-version>
    <version.maven-surefire-plugin>2.15</version.maven-surefire-plugin>
    <version.maven-bundle-plugin>2.3.7</version.maven-bundle-plugin>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>

    <!-- the version of the BOM, defining all the dependency versions -->
    <fabric.version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</fabric.version>

    <!-- fabric8 deploy profile configuration -->
    <fabric8.profile>quickstarts-cxf-soap</fabric8.profile>
    <fabric8.parentProfiles>feature-cxf</fabric8.parentProfiles>
    <fabric8.features>fabric-cxf cxf-jaxws</fabric8.features>

      <!-- the version of the JBoss Fuse BOM, defining all the dependency versions -->
      <jboss.fuse.bom.version>6.2.1.redhat-084</jboss.fuse.bom.version>
  </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.fuse.bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
    <!--
        For coding the example, we don't actually depend on any CXF classes - we only use the JAX-WS
        standard annotations
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        For logging, we will use SLF4J, which is also available in the container by default.
      -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--
      Add the slf4j-log4j12 dependency jar for testing
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>shared</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Skip Test by default and enable them only in Test profile -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven-surefire-plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Import-Package>
              javax.jws;version="[0,3)",
              javax.wsdl,
              javax.xml.namespace,
              org.apache.cxf.helpers,
              org.osgi.service.blueprint,
              io.fabric8.cxf.endpoint,
              org.apache.cxf.transport.http
            </Import-Package>
            <Import-Service>org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler;
                osgi.service.blueprint.namespace=http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
            </Import-Service>
            <Export-Package>
              io.fabric8.quickstarts.soap
            </Export-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.redhat-621084</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>process-classes</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>java2ws</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <className>io.fabric8.quickstarts.soap.HelloWorld</className>
              <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
              <attachWsdl>false</attachWsdl>
              <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <!--
          this plugin will use the fabric.* properties to configure its behaviour
          see the Properties section here: http://fabric8.io/gitbook/mavenPlugin.html
        -->
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.redhat-621084</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

    <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <properties>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <defaultGoal>verify</defaultGoal>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

I am using below software:

- Maven 3.6.3
- JDK 1.8
- JBoss Fuse 7.2.0

Any idea how to resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED - this is the issue with RED HAT JBOSS version. I have downloaded version 6.3.0 and it runs as expected, generated the WSDL file.